# MWAA requirements install takes to long (timeout)

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, airflow, mwaa

Due to a maintenance our stack had to be refreshed. The requirements file hasn't change since the last time. Yet, this time the installation had exceeded 9 minutes and had gone into timeout. No packages are accessible.
The current requirements.txt looks like this :

```
algoliasearch==2.4.0
apache-airflow==2.4.3
apache-airflow-providers-sftp==4.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-google==6.5.0
apache-airflow-providers-amazon==8.1.0
apache-airflow-providers-postgres==5.5.0
apache-airflow-providers-mysql==5.1.0
delighted==4.0.0
github3.py==4.0.1
jellyfish==0.9.0
mailjet-rest==1.3.4
mysqlclient==2.0.1
oauth2client==4.1.3
paramiko==2.8.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
pygsheets==2.0.3.1
pymongo==3.10.1
rtbhouse-sdk==8.0.0
searchads-api>=1.5.2
simple_salesforce==1.10.1
sshtunnel==0.4.0
stripe==2.55.1
xmltodict==0.12.0
```

I've referred to best practices (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/best-practices-dependencies.html) and I tried to use a requirements.txt that looks like this :

```
--find-links /usr/local/airflow/plugins
--no-index

algoliasearch
apache-airflow
apache-airflow-providers-sftp
apache-airflow-providers-google
apache-airflow-providers-amazon
apache-airflow-providers-postgres
apache-airflow-providers-mysql
delighted
github3.py
jellyfish
mailjet-rest
mysqlclient
oauth2client
paramiko
PyYAML
pygsheets
pymongo
rtbhouse-sdk
searchads-api
simple_salesforce
sshtunnel
stripe
xmltodict
```

I uploaded a zip within my packages .whl to S3. The solution seems to work (according to Cloudwatch logs) but the installation starts all over again (during 2 hours) to finally crash with a timeout.

Do you have any idea what the problem is? Can I increase the timeout period?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and seems like there is, indeed, a way to increase the timeout period: just add '--default-timeout=9000' after 'pip install' inside your docker file.

E.g.

`FROM python:3.9`

`...`

`COPY requirements.txt .`

`RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --default-timeout=9000`